# Interacting with activeSheet, activeCell in a stand-alone script

Tags: google-apps-script

I created a google sheet that stores info row by row that I send out in different emails as templates. I'd like to give a copy of the file to my colleagues, but I'm figuring out it's probably better from a version-control standpoint to deploy the script as an add-on so they can install it individually, yet I retain centralized control of the code. However, my code uses a decent amount of ActiveSpreadsheet() and ActiveSheet() and activeCell() functions that apparently only container-bound scripts can use.

Anyone have any recommendations as to how to replace the following lines in a stand-alone script? Also any commentary on my idea to change my script to a stand-alone script to deploy as an add-on would be appreciated!

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var scriptRow = sheet.getActiveCell().getRow(); 
var tst1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('Draft create failed');
```

Comment: You can deploy a container bound [add-on](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#add-ons). That way you don't have to modify the code.

Comment: Ah sorry, I forgot to mention my last complaint about the container-bound add-on. The user can edit the script in 'script editor' if it's container bound, right? Is there no way to protect the add-on?

Comment: Once you publish an add-on, the user will never be able to access the code. They only interact with your add-on via add-on menu( Add on menu->"Your add on"->Start), if you directly share the sheet with your code then they will be able to access the code.

Comment: Ah, right now my email is included in the list of approved tester accounts. Maybe tester accounts, but you're saying non-testing accounts won't? If so, that solves my problem :)

Comment: So you have already published your add-on in a limited capacity? Have you installed your add-on to a new sheet with a different account (tester account) and you can see the code?

Comment: I published it privately to tester accounts yes, I have not tried it with a colleague, which I should have. I will Monday and if it works will promptly close this question, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead of the above code:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("your-spreadsheet-id").getSheetByName("your-table-name");
var scriptRow = sheet.getActiveCell().getRow(); 
var tst1 = sheet.toast('Draft create failed');
```

It's hard to say if an add-on would be good. Depends on the exact work the script is doing: You can either publish it as Add-on, Web app or API.

Comment: The second line doesn't work with standalone script. The method getActiveCell() is a special method available only to container-bound script. See "Special methods" section here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound